# Display same form data in the input text fields even after form submission

Tags: forms, prestashop-1.7

```
$fields_form = array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Configure Settings'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
            ),
            'description' => $form_desc,
        'input' => array(
            array(
              'type'     => 'text',
              'label'    => $this->l('textfield1'),
              'name'     => 'username',
              'size'     => 50,
              'class' => 'fixed-width-xxl',
              'required' => true
          ),
            array(
              'type'     => 'password',
              'label'    => $this->l('textfield2'),
              'name'     => 'password',
              'size'     => 50,
              'class' => 'fixed-width-xl',
              'required' => true,
          ),
            ),
          'submit' => array(
              'name' => 'submitconfigureoptions',
              'title' => $this->l('Save'),
              'icon' => 'process-icon-save',
              'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'

          ),
        )
    );
```

I have a form with four input text fields and a submit button.So,after submitting the form the same values I entered in the input text fields must be displayed in the form after page refresh.

Comment: In that case you can save fields in local storage and can display. it will be helpful if you can provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

To persist values in Helper Form you can use the following code:

```
$helper->fields_value['field_name'] = 'field_value';
```

Add this code before the generateForm() function and this will add the values to your fields before page load.